# Steam crash on playonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux, steam

I'm trying to install steam using playonlinux/wine. There was nothing wrong with the installation, but whenever I try to login, steam crashes. After enabling the debugging mode, i got the log below.

```
[01/28/13 20:45:09] - Running wine-1.5.10 --version
wine-1.5.10

PlayOnLinux logfile
-------------------
Date: 01/28/13 20:45:09

> PlayOnLinux Version
  4.1.1
> uname -a
  Linux ubuntu 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:31:23 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
> lsb_release -a

> wine --version
  wine-1.5.10
> POL_WINEVERSION
  1.5.10
> WINEPREFIX
  /home/mehmet/.PlayOnLinux//wineprefix/Steam
> glxinfo \| grep rendering

> glxinfo \| grep renderer

> OpenGL libs (Direct rendering testing)



[01/28/13 20:46:04] - Running wine-1.5.10 cmd /c echo %ProgramFiles%
C:\Program Files
[01/28/13 20:46:08] - Running wine-1.5.10 cmd /c echo %ProgramFiles%
C:\Program Files
[01/28/13 20:46:17] - Running wine-1.5.10 msiexec /i SteamInstall.msi /q
Steam Client Service install completed.fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
err:mscoree:LoadLibraryShim error reading registry key for installroot
fixme:msi:ITERATE_CreateShortcuts poorly handled shortcut format, advertised shortcut
fixme:advapi:SetNamedSecurityInfoW L"MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Valve\\Steam" 4 4 (nil) (nil) 0x133a10 (nil)
fixme:advapi:SetNamedSecurityInfoW L"C:\\Program Files\\Steam" 1 4 (nil) (nil) 0x133a10 (nil)
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_ProcessImageFileName 0x133b30, L"C:\\Program Files\\Steam\\Steam.exe"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_app_put_Name 0x133b30, L"Steam"
fixme:hnetcfg:fw_apps_Add 0x1334c8, 0x133b30
fixme:service:QueryServiceObjectSecurity 0x133b30 4 0x33f98c 512 0x33fbc0 - semi-stub
fixme:service:SetServiceObjectSecurity 0x133b30 4 0x33fb8c
[01/28/13 20:46:26] - Running wine-1.5.10 regedit /home/mehmet/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/regkey.reg
[01/28/13 20:46:26] - Content of /home/mehmet/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/regkey.reg
-----------
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Direct3D]
"VideoMemorySize"="1024"
-----------
[01/28/13 20:46:26] - Running wine-1.5.10 regedit /home/mehmet/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/override-dll.reg
[01/28/13 20:46:26] - Content of /home/mehmet/.PlayOnLinux//tmp/override-dll.reg
-----------
REGEDIT4

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\DllOverrides]
"*dwrite"=""
-----------
[01/28/13 20:46:33] - Running wine-1.5.10 Steam.exe
[01/28/13 20:46:45] - Running wine-1.5.10 Steam.exe
[01/28/13 20:47:23] - Running wine-1.5.10 Steam.exe
[0128/205207:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(111)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  40321
  Current serial number in output stream:  40321
[01/28/13 21:05:47] - Running wine-1.5.10 Steam.exe
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036b20, 0x3f036b18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036b58, 0x3f036b50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036ae8, 0x3f036ae0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036b90, 0x3f036b88
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036bc8, 0x3f036bc0
fixme:process:SetProcessShutdownParameters (00000100, 00000000): partial stub.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x172d6c4, overlapped 0x1538058): stub
fixme:winsock:WSALookupServiceBeginW (0x172d7c4 0x00000ff0 0x172d80c) Stub!
[0128/210549:ERROR:network_change_notifier_win.cc(111)] WSALookupServiceBegin failed with: 8
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {47a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc6f}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036b20, 0x3f036b18
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {58a9201e-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361bc70}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036b58, 0x3f036b50
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {3fa9201e-73b0-43fe-9821-7e145359bc6f}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036ae8, 0x3f036ae0
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {1432afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b433}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036b90, 0x3f036b88
fixme:advapi:EventRegister {4372afee-73b0-42ce-9821-7e134361b519}, 0x3f0057f0, 0x3f036bc8, 0x3f036bc0
fixme:heap:HeapSetInformation (nil) 1 (nil) 0
fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {77f10cf0-3db5-4966-b520-b7c54fd35ed6} could be created for context 0x1
fixme:wbemprox:wbem_locator_ConnectServer unsupported flags
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_SetBlanket 0xf17bf660, 0x1fb2e8, 10, 0, (null), 3, 3, (nil), 0x00000000
fixme:wbemprox:client_security_Release 0xf17bf660
fixme:wbemprox:enum_class_object_Next timeout not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {dff32fea-3331-48da-a272-ccfc238695be} not registered
err:ole:CoGetClassObject class {dff32fea-3331-48da-a272-ccfc238695be} not registered
err:ole:create_server class {dff32fea-3331-48da-a272-ccfc238695be} not registered
fixme:ole:CoGetClassObject CLSCTX_REMOTE_SERVER not supported
err:ole:CoGetClassObject no class object {dff32fea-3331-48da-a272-ccfc238695be} could be created for context 0x17
fixme:winhttp:WinHttpDetectAutoProxyConfigUrl discovery via DHCP not supported
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:advapi:EventUnregister deadbeef: stub
fixme:ntdll:NtLockFile I/O completion on lock not implemented yet
fixme:win:RegisterDeviceNotificationA (hwnd=0x200b2, filter=0x32d3cc,flags=0x00000004) returns a fake device notification handle!
X Error of failed request:  BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  19 (X_GLXQueryServerString)
  Serial number of failed request:  1017
  Current serial number in output stream:  1017
```

By the way I'm kinda new to Ubuntu. So, if you think I should give you more details please let me know.

Thanks in advance, have a lovely day...

Comment: Please see this: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Valve also include the specs of your equipment. Steam is usually installed via an Ubuntu client which does all the work. The page provided is very comprehensive about it. Good luck

Comment: To close voters: I think the solution, even as it stands now, is valuable enough to warrant keeping this question open. I've posted it as a CW answer.

Comment: Given that the Linux version of Steam was released 2.5 weeks after this question, I don't think it's useful to keep around.

Answer (score 1):

The OP solved the problem (originally reported in the answer):

> After hours, I realized i didn't install my video card driver. If
>   you're having the same problem, don't forget to install your video
>   card's driver.